# How to get the Angular value in javascript function?

Tags: angularjs, html

Here i want to get the sliderValue in onchange event of javascript function.
Currently I am using document.queryselector instead of i want to set it in scope of sliderValue.

Code:
`<input id="slider"  type ="range" min="{{sliderMin}}" onchange="updateSlider()" max="{{sliderMax}}" step="{{sliderStep}}" value="{{sliderValue}}" />`

Comment: Try ng-change="updateSlider(sliderValue)"

Comment: Can't you use ng-change instead of onchange?

Comment: yes i tried ng-change but it not working properly in all browser getting struck in firefox.

Comment: It should work. What's wrong with firefox ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
onchange="angular.element(this).scope().updateSlider(this)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't agree with Sid response. Angular best practice is to use [ngchange](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange):

```
<input id="slider" type ="range" min="{{sliderMin}}" ng-change="updateSlider(sliderValue)" 
max="{{sliderMax}}" step="{{sliderStep}}" value="{{sliderValue}}" />
```